# qt mysql connection error

Tags: c++, linux, qt, centos

i am testing out a database connection on QT but i get this error

```
[root@server env]# make
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../../../lib64/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I../../../include/QtCore -I../../../include/QtGui -I../../../include -I. -I. -o test.o test.cpp
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:20: error: cannot convert ‘QSqlDatabase’ to ‘int’ in return
test.cpp: At global scope:
test.cpp:23: error: ‘Database’ has not been declared
make: *** [test.o] Error 1
```

this is the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "/usr/include/mysql/mysql.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QtSql/QtSql>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    cout << "SHELL = " << getenv("SHELL") << endl;
    cout << "SHELL = " << getenv("TERM") << endl;

    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
    db.setHostName("xxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxx");
    db.setDatabaseName("SAMS");
    db.setUserName("xxxxxxxx");
    db.setPassword("xxxxxxxxxx");
    if (!db.open()) qDebug() << "Failed to connect to mysql as user testuser";
    return db;
}

void Database::closeDb(){
    QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase("QMYSQL");
}
```

any idea???

**UPDATE:**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "/usr/include/mysql/mysql.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QtSql/QtSql>

using namespace std;

void conn() {

    cout << "SHELL = " << getenv("SHELL") << endl;
    cout << "SHELL = " << getenv("TERM") << endl;

    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
    db.setHostName("xxxxxxxx");
    db.setDatabaseName("xxxxxxxx");
    db.setUserName("xxxxx");
    db.setPassword("xxxxxxxxxx");
    if (!db.open()) qDebug() << "Failed to connect to mysql as user testuser";
}

void closeDb(){
    QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase("QMYSQL");
}



[root@server env]# make
g++ -c -m64 -pipe -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../../../lib64/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I. -I../../../include/QtCore -I../../../include/QtGui -I../../../include -I. -I. -o test.o test.cpp
g++ -m64 -Wl,-O1 -o env test.o     -lQtGui -lQtCore -lpthread 
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
test.o: In function `closeDb()':
/usr/local/dev/env/test.cpp:23: undefined reference to `QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase(QString const&)'
test.o: In function `QString':
/usr/include/QtCore/qstring.h:683: undefined reference to `QSqlDatabase::defaultConnection'
test.o: In function `conn()':
/usr/local/dev/env/test.cpp:14: undefined reference to `QSqlDatabase::addDatabase(QString const&, QString const&)'
/usr/local/dev/env/test.cpp:15: undefined reference to `QSqlDatabase::setHostName(QString const&)'
/usr/local/dev/env/test.cpp:16: undefined reference to `QSqlDatabase::setDatabaseName(QString const&)'
/usr/local/dev/env/test.cpp:17: undefined reference to `QSqlDatabase::setUserName(QString const&)'
/usr/local/dev/env/test.cpp:18: undefined reference to `QSqlDatabase::setPassword(QString const&)'
/usr/local/dev/env/test.cpp:19: undefined reference to `QSqlDatabase::open()'
/usr/local/dev/env/test.cpp:19: undefined reference to `QSqlDatabase::~QSqlDatabase()'
/usr/local/dev/env/test.cpp:19: undefined reference to `QSqlDatabase::~QSqlDatabase()'
/usr/local/dev/env/test.cpp:14: undefined reference to `QSqlDatabase::~QSqlDatabase()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [env] Error 1
```

**update:**

this worked..

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "/usr/include/mysql/mysql.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QtSql/QtSql>

using namespace std;

void conn() {

    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
    db.setHostName("xxxxxxxxxxx");
    db.setDatabaseName("SAMS");
    db.setUserName("xxxxxxxx");
    db.setPassword("xxxxxxxx");
    if (!db.open()) {
        qDebug() << "Failed to connect to mysql as user testuser";
    }
    else {
        qDebug() << "hello";
    }
}

void closeDb() {
    QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase("QMYSQL");
}

int main() {

    cout << "SHELL = " << getenv("SHELL") << endl;
    cout << "SHELL = " << getenv("TERM") << endl;
    conn();
    return 0;

}
```

i had to add

```
QT += core gui sql
```

to the project file..

Answer (score 0):

You are returning your `QSqlDatabase` in your `int main()` function and this is invalid because `QSqlDatabase` is not `int`. Why are you returning it? If you want the return type to describe success then use `-1` and otherwise `0`, for instance.

As for the second error, you haven't any class defined called `Database` so you can't define the method `Database::closeDb()`. Instead create a function to do what you want:

```
void closeDb() {
  QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase("QMYSQL");
}
```

But I don't see the purpose of `closeDb()` when you are not using it anyway.

Comment: That is because you still need your `int main()` function because it is the entry point of the program. The undefined references errors means that the compiler cannot find the necessary header/class information. You need to make sure that you have those for `QSqlDatabase` etc. Note that this was not a problem in the first snippet you posted - so you might have changed the compile statement.